# In a box there are 3 white, two black balls. Players A,B,C one by one draw balls from the box. Find the probability of winning each player.

Tags: probability

White balls are returned to the box, black balls are kept. A player has won when he has drawn the last ball(black). And if $X$ is the random variable the represents the number of draws , find the distribution of $X$.
 This is what i need clarification on:

Answer- Let $P_n$- be the probability that in $n$ draws one black ball has been drawn (exactly). After using formula of complete probability we get $$P_n=\frac{3}{4} P_{n-1}+ (\frac{3}{5})^{n-1} \frac{2}{5},; n=2,3... P_1= \frac{2}{5}$$

What are the hypotheses here?

$$P\{ X=n\}= \frac{1}{4}P_{n-1}; n=2,3...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_n=p(\text{the nth ball is the first black ball drawn})$

Then $$P_n=\left(\frac 35\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac25\right)$$

Let $Q_m=p(\text{the mth ball after this is the last and winning black ball})$

Then$$Q_m=\left(\frac 34\right)^{m-1}\left(\frac14\right)$$

Now let $X$ be the number of draws taken by the players collectively.

We have $$p(X=\text{ n followed by m})=\left(\frac 35\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac25\right)\left(\frac 34\right)^{m-1}\left(\frac14\right)$$

Now let $N=m+n$ and set $m-1=N-n-1$

To get the total probability $p(X=N)$, we need to sum this expression for $n=1$ to $n=N-1$

Eventually we get $$p(X=N)=\frac 89\left(\frac 34\right)^N\left(1-\left(\frac 45\right)^{N-1}\right)$$

As a double check, you will find the sum to infinity of the probabilities is 1.